# Immedate v. Regular Functions

Tags: javascript

What are significant differences between `immediate` and `regular` functions?

**immediate**

```
(function() {
    console.log("intermediate function");
})();                 // pass arguments inside of ()
```

**regular** (note - I'm not sure if *regular* is an official/accepted term)

```
function fn() {
  console.log("not intermediate function");   
}
fn();
```

Comment: why `-`? if it's a dumb/obvious question, please let me know why

Comment: One creates a name in the enclosing variable scope, the other does not. That's the difference. But certainly you knew this already.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate, @cookiemonster. I voted for it.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st one is *usually* called an IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression).
The second one is a regular function.

The **both** are functions.

And they **both** have their own scope.

In the second one `fn` is in the global scope.

Comment: @watson: No, the name would not be global.

Comment: @watson nope, it would not. It would be local to the IIFE.

Comment: `fn` is in the enclosing scope, which may nor may not be global.

Comment: @cookiemonster true, but the way the OP wrote it I inferred the global scope.

Comment: I agree. I should have noted that I only point this out because I've encountered people who believed that function declaration syntax always creates globals. So just to keep it clear for others.

Comment: Question: "What are significant differences...". Answer: "They both are / have ...". Uhm, ok ...

Comment: why does `(function() { console.log("this:", this); ... ` output `window`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith that is because `this` in that scope is **still** window :-)

Comment: @KevinMeredith Google the `this` keyword for yourself and learn how it works, it's a very fundamental concept in JS that you should know already/learn ASAP if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

The first difference is the first one is anonymous , the second one is not.

The second difference is the first one is a pattern to express an intent , the second is just a function  declaration and call.

That pattern is usefull if you intend to write some statements that might polute the global scope. for instance.

```
 (function(){
   var $ = {};
   doSomething($);
 }());
 $('#foo').animate();
```

You dont have to care wether $ is already used by jQuery or not because it will not be overriden in the global scope(just in the local function scope). You can write code with less side effects since you are creating a scope then executing some code.

All the variables declared in the scope will be local to the scope.

And since you might want to execute the code only once , naming the function is not necessary.

You might want to use it if you write a library for the browser and do a bunch of stuffs before returning an object. That way you know you wont accidentally override something a previous library has declared.

Answer (score 0):

First one is IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression).In a simple way to    understand As its name define itself it  need not to call,it is anonymous function and it call itself(default):

```
   (function() {
    console.log("IIFE function");
    })();
```

Second one is regular function and it is called by calling some function,here it is called by function fn():

```
    function fn() {    
    console.log("not IIFE function");       
    }  
       fn();
```

for more information about function and pattern in javascript use
    Learning JavaScript Design Patterns   http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Answer (score -1):

They are both functions, one is just defined within the body of another function (an anonymous function is used in the first case).

The scope of variables will be the containing function, or global if there is none.